# Mongoose syntax : how to find data where parameter in between two fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to use Mongoose to find a record of data in MongoDB Atlas. The aqlLevel and batchSize is the value that already know, but inspectionLevel, lotSizeMin and lotSizeMax is the field of one of the table in MongoDB Atlas. I've tried the syntax that without where condition and it works. However, with the where condition I can't get anything back from the table in MongoDB Atlas. Can anyone help me with the Mongoose syntax so that I can find the data with where condition?

The piece of code that I would like to use to search

```
let aqlLevel = find.aqlLevel;
let batchSize = find.batchSize;
let findSampleSizeCodeLetter = await SampleSize.find({inspectionLevel: aqlLevel})
                                                   .where(batchSize).gte({lotSizeMin}).lte({lotSizeMax}).exec();
```

The schema of the table is like this below:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const schema = new Schema({
    lotSizeMin: { type: Number},
    lotSizeMax: { type: Number},
    inspectionLevel: {type: String},
    sampleSizeCode: {type: String}
}, { collection : 'SampleSizeCodeLetter' });


schema.set('toJSON', {
    virtuals: true,
    versionKey: false,
    transform: function (doc, ret) {
        delete ret._id;
        delete ret.hash;
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('SampleSizeCodeLetter', schema);
```

Comment: Can you find any documents in Mongo Atlas with same filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code below successfully solve my problem:

```
let aqlLevel = find.aqlLevel;
let batchSize = find.batchSize;
let findSampleSizeCodeLetter = await SampleSize.find({inspectionLevel: aqlLevel})
  .where('lotSizeMin').lt(batchSize)
  .where('lotSizeMax').gt(batchSize).exec();
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code both code

```
let findSampleSizeCodeLetter = await SampleSize.find({
inspectionLevel: aqlLevel,
lotSizeMin:{$gte:batchSize},
lotSizeMax:{$lte:batchSize}
})
```

or this one

```
let findSampleSizeCodeLetter = await SampleSize.aggregate([
{match:
{
inspectionLevel: aqlLevel,
lotSizeMin:{$gte:batchSize},
lotSizeMax:{$lte:batchSize}
}
}]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, these two solutions that you provided did not work in my case.